# ORM for Mono, MonoTouch and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: nhibernate, orm, mono, xamarin.ios, domain-model

I am planning an application which will re-use entities between an ASP.NET MVC web app, a WinForms app and a MonoTouch iPad app.

I've considered using (Fluent) NHibernate as the ORM, but I am concerned that if I design my entities for use on WinForms, when I create the iPad app I will have to duplicate the entities, and remap them for SQLLite on the iPad (No NHibernate on MonoTouch).

Is there an ORM where I can get away with:

1. Using the same entities (This should be possible if the entities are abstracted from the mappings as per Fluent NHibernate)
2. Using the same mappings (This is possibly harder to achieve and not as important

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your entities are just POCOs so you don't need to duplicate them. You could use NH which works on Mono, and then write a cut down version of your repositories for MonoTouch, I doubt you would need to implement everything, just what you require, for MonoTouch. IoC FTW.

Comment: I agree - the POCO's will be the same. I was trying to get out of using 2 ORM's and therefore having to map the objects on each project seperately. Alas, it seems that this isn't easy and it'll probably take less time to map and test than to do it by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using ViciProject CoolStorage and it is brilliant. Recommended!

http://viciproject.com/wiki/projects/coolstorage/home

Comment: This looks good - though I am not sure I would use this on the server side too. Thanks, looks like a winner for the MT side :)

Comment: We use it on the server side as well, written in .NET 4.0 and deployed as IIS service in cluster, works great. The simplicity of this API is just the right thing for us and speeds development a lot.